# Did the Elders call themselves Elders on Danu Talis?

Tags: secrets-of-immortal-nicholas-flamel

The race of Elders and Great Elders includes beings such as Mars, Bastet, Aten, Quetzalcoatl, Prometheus, Areop-Enap, and lots of others that we encounter over the course of the series. These beings are referred to as "Elders", universally that I can see.

The word "Elder" means "older". This would make sense now, as the Elders are certainly older than the humani. This makes less sense when 10,000 years ago they ruled from Danu Talis. The humani were newly created and not a significant factor as of yet, and the Next Generation did not exist. There wasn't really anyone that they were *elder* to - the Earthlords, Ancients, and Archons all preceded them. They were the *youngest* of the Great Races.

Did they refer to themselves as "Elders" even in the time of Danu Talis?